# Conditional Number Formatting In Java

Tags: java, java1.4

How can I format Floats in Java so that the float component is displayed only if it's not zero? For example:

```
123.45 -> 123.45
99.0   -> 99
23.2   -> 23.2
45.0   -> 45
```

Edit: I forgot to mention - I'm still on Java 1.4 - sorry!

Comment: DecimalFormat is available in jdk 1.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and specify # in the pattern it only displays the value if it is not zero.

See my question [How do I format a number in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Sample Code

```
 DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

    double[] doubles = {123.45, 99.0, 23.2, 45.0};
    for(int i=0;i<doubles.length;i++){
        System.out.println(format.format(doubles[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class, e.g. new DecimalFormat("0.##").format(99.0) will return "99".

Answer (score 0):

```
new Formatter().format( "%f", myFloat )
```