# How to remove .0 after a double while converting to string

Tags: java, string, double

What is the best way to convert a double `xx.xx` to the following strings in Java?

- `22.0` to `22`
- `22.1` to `22.1`
- `22.22` to `22.22`
- `22.00` to `22`

If the decimal part is 0, just need the whole number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487/conditional-number-formatting-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Use the class [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
double d = 2.0;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
String formated = formatter.format(d).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code finally decided is as below.

If you use DecimalFormat and specify # in the pattern it only displays the value if it is not zero.

```
    Double d=22.00 
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    format.format(d);
```