# How do I format a decimal value to have appropriate amount of trailing spaces

Tags: java

I have a double value which could be either `9.2 or 13.45 or 198.789 or 110.8.`
How do I format this to `9.2000 or 13.4500 198.7890 or 110.8000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java) SO post can be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Decimal Format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

`new DecimalFormat("#0.0000").format(9.2); //"9.2000"`

Answer (score 1):

See: The DecimalFormat Class under

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format()` to some extent. For example:

```
String.format("%07.3f", 1.23d); //prints 001.230
```

The format is `%0<width>.<precision>f` where, `<width>` is the minimum number of character (including the dot) that should be printed padded with 0's (in my example there are 7 characters); `<precision>` is the number of digits after the decimal point.

This method will work for simple formatting, and you cannot control the rounding (rounding is is half-up by default).