# How to remove the " .0" in a whole number when using double in java?

Tags: java, android, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format a number in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

I have problems in using Double. When the result is a whole number, it would display with a " .0" like 1.0, 2.0.

Can anyone help me how to remove that .0 in a whole number?

Comment: Closing of this question is not right as it is not a generic "How to format a number in Java" question, but rather a question on specific style of formatting.

Comment: It should rather be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) the string that you are displaying.

Answer (score 62):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class Asdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
        format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

        Double asdf = 2.0;
        Double asdf2 = 2.11;
        Double asdf3 = 2000.11;
        System.out.println( format.format(asdf) );
        System.out.println( format.format(asdf2) );
        System.out.println( format.format(asdf3) );
    }

}
```

prints:

```
2
2.11
2,000.11
```

Using

```
DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("#.#"); //not okay!!!
```

is not right as it messes with 10^3, 10^6, etc. separators.

2000.11 would be displayed as "2000.11" instead of "2,000.11"

This is of course if you want to display numbers properly formatted, not just using improper toString().

Also note, that formatting may different based on users Locale and DecimalFormat should be initialized accordingly using a factory method with user's Locale as an argument:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
 if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
     ((DecimalFormat) f).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
 }
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

**UPDATE**
This formatting string works fine also without calling the extra method:

```
    DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("#,###.#");
   //format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 30):

You need to use DecimalFormat to format your double.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.#");
      System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(2.0)); //prints 2
}
```

Comment: `DecimalFormat("#")` is enough

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - Thanks - so used to having 2 decimal points .. so it came out of habit!

Comment: Is this code applicable to android?

Comment: @ikzton - Did you try the code yet?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad no, it's not. He did not say he wanted to remove decimal numbers. 2.0 should become 2, 2.1 should become 2.1, not 2

Comment: yup.. but when I press calculate the android will quit. where should I put this? on the onCreate Bundle? and create a new public void?

Comment: @CoolBeans using #.# messes with 10^3, 10^6, etc. formatting.

Comment: Works at the cost of making your result a string.