# Getting trash after parsing a valid number?

Tags: java, parsing, floating-point

Alright, so I got a test program:

```
public class ParseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "-0.000051";
        System.out.println(s + " != " + Float.parseFloat(s));
    }
}
```

and it's not out putting the same number on both sides. This is the output:

```
-0.000051 != -5.1E-5
```

So, why isn't it outputting the same number on both sides?

Comment: It *is* the same number, dude.  One is decimal, the other is exponential: both notations show the same value!  Your "println()" is implicitly doing "Float.toString()".  If you want a different notation, look at "String.format()".  EX: String.format("%.2f", floatValue);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same number just [different scientific representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation),

For example:

```
100 = 1E2
```

and

```
0.1 = 1E-1
```

---

**How to get same representation ?**

If you want the same representation then use `BigDecimal`

```
System.out.println(s + " != " + new BigDecimal(s));
```

---

**Who is converting it to this format ?**

when you convert primitive to String by for example

```
float f = 100.123;
String result = "" + f;
```

It calls the [`Float.valueOf(f)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Float.java.html) which inturns calls the [`Float.toString()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Float.java.html) which inturn calls the [`new FloatingDecimal(f).toJavaFormatString();`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html) this is where this stuff is encapsulated

Comment: Why did it change the expression?

Comment: @CyanPrime It didn't. It _is_ the same number. See [Scientific notation on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: For other outputs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java.