# How to Apply mask to string value

Tags: java, android

i want to apply format mask like "#0" to my number field which is string like "6000",
i tried different types of formatting,but it didnt help,can anyone tell me how to handle this in android please

I am looking for something like when i do this `formatString("6000", "#,##0.00")` it should give me the formatted output `6,000.00`

Comment: show us what you have tried. Also some sample input and output would help to understand the question better.

Comment: i tried with maskFormatter class but as this is not supported by android it gave runTimeException.am looking for something like when i do this formatString("6000", "#,##0.00") it should give me the formatted output 6,000.00

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
    String yourString = "6000";
    double value = Double.valueOf(yourString);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    System.out.println(df.format(value));
```

Comment: @jayanthithakur Than please don't forget to accept the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your string "6000" to a number e.g.

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("6000");
```

Then use `DecimalFormat` like explained here: [How do I format a number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)