# How to display a number with always 2 decimal points using BigDecimal?

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal, decimal-point

I am using *BigDecimal* to get some price values. Requirement is something like this, what ever the value we fetch from database, the displayed valued should have 2 decimal points.

Eg:

> fetched value is 1 - should be displayed as 1.00
>   fetched value is 1.7823 - should be displayed as 1.78

I am using `setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` but still some places, if the data from DB is a whole number then the same is being displayed !!

I mean if the value is 0 from DB its displayed as 0 only. I want that to be displayed as 0.00

Thanks

Comment: I think you can find your answer right here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/50543/61624

Comment: thanks daniel :)that was too fast reply..

but i am already using the bigdecimal.round_half_up with setscale(2)
it works when u have number like 2.12 or 4.2343.
when the value is a whole number like just 2 then i want that to be displayed as 2.00 and this is where i am failing !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a number in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Answer (score 70):

BigDecimal is immutable, any operation on it including setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) produces a new BigDecimal. Correct code should be

```java
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1);
bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // this does change bd
bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(bd);
```

output

```
1.00
```

Note - Since Java 9 `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` has been deprecated and you should now use `RoundingMode.ROUND_HALF_UP`.

Comment: This is deprecated since Java 9, use `.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`

Comment: I think he meant "this DOES NOT change bd". The second line is not necessary

Answer (score 15):

you can use the round up format

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2.22222);
System.out.println(bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP));
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 14):

To format numbers in JAVA you can use:

```
 System.out.printf("%1$.2f", d);
```

where d is your variable or number

or

```
 DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");  // this will helps you to always keeps in two decimal places
 System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

Comment: Better to use ```new DecimalFormat("##0.00");```, because with ```##.00``` for ```0``` you will get ```.00``` instead of ```0.00```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like `NumberFormat` with appropriate locale to [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(bigDecimal);
```

Comment: This will print the currency symbol, e.g. $, along with the number, which the OP did not mention he wanted.  But like the thought of using the currency instance here for readability.

Answer (score 2):

BigDecimal.setScale would work.

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help.

```
protected String getLocalizedBigDecimalValue(BigDecimal input, Locale locale) {
    final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return numberFormat.format(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **custom annotation** in this manner:
The custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface FormatBigDecimal {
    String format() default "0.00";
}
```

And then you can apply the annotation on a field and in the constructor call the implementation method as shown below:

```
public class TestClass {
   

    @FormatBigDecimal
    private BigDecimal myDecimal;
    public TestClass(BigDecimal myDecimal) throws ParseException, IllegalAccessException {
        this.myDecimal = myDecimal;
        formatBigDecimalFields();
    }

    public void setMyDecimal(BigDecimal myDecimal) {
        this.myDecimal = myDecimal;
    }

    public BigDecimal getMyDecimal() {
        return myDecimal;
    }
/**
In the above method, we are using reflection to get all the fields declared in the class. Then, we are iterating over all the fields and checking whether the @FormatBigDecimal annotation is present on the field. If it is present, we are making the field accessible and getting its value.

We are also getting the format string from the @FormatBigDecimal annotation and using it to create a DecimalFormat object with the desired format. Then, we are formatting the value of the field using the DecimalFormat object and storing the formatted value in a string.

Finally, we are parsing the formatted value back into a BigDecimal object and setting it as the value of the field.
**/
    public void formatBigDecimalFields() throws IllegalAccessException, ParseException {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(FormatBigDecimal.class)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) field.get(this);
                FormatBigDecimal formatAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(FormatBigDecimal.class);
                String formatString = formatAnnotation.format();
                NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
                DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) format;
                decimalFormat.applyPattern(formatString);
                String formattedValue = decimalFormat.format(value);
                BigDecimal formattedDecimal = new BigDecimal(formattedValue);
                field.set(this, formattedDecimal);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To Use it:

```
 TestClass testClass = new TestClass(new BigDecimal("10000.899"));
        System.out.println(testClass.getMyDecimal());
```

will give: `10000.90`