# BigDecimal Round to 2 decimal places and then to one significant figure

Tags: java, android

How do i round a BigDecimal to 2 decimal places and then to one significant figure?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515640/how-to-display-a-number-with-always-2-decimal-points-using-bigdecimal

Comment: Both don't show how to get the 2 decimal places AND significant figure

Comment: Why do you want to round twice?  This can give you incorrect results.  3.496 is closer to 3 than to 4, but if you round 3.496 to two decimal places, you get 3.5, which will round to 4, which probably is not what you want, unless you have a real good explanation.

Comment: Under the legislative document i'm working with, it requires that step by step process, so unfortunately no real room to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using a class in android **DecimalFormat**.

```
private String formatMagnitude(double magnitude) 
{
    DecimalFormat magnitudeFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    return magnitudeFormat.format(magnitude);
}
```