# How can i add extra digit to a BigDecimal?

Tags: java

In below code, user will enter `firstAmount` and `secondAmount`. Then program will run and do this calculation `firstAmount*secondAmount/123` and answer will be in `totalAmount` variable. Further program will take the `totalAmount` and do some extra calculations, but before that i want to add extra digits to `totalAmount`. For example if by calculating `totalAmount` gets amount something like `23.021` that is okay. But it doesn't have any decimal point i would add that to it, for example if `totalAmount` gets amount `41` now there is no decimal point so i would add `.00` means after that toalAmount will be `4.00`. How do i do that ? How can i add extra digits if there is no already?  Below is my code where i want this stuff to be happen.

```
switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()){
    case 0:
    {
    
    totalAmount = firstAmount.multiply(secondAmount).divide(new BigDecimal("123"), MathContext.DECIMAL128);

   // before next calculation i want to add extra digits if there is no decimal point in the totalAmount

    nextCalculation = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
    
    break;
    }
```

Comment: do you mean you want to set the scale of the BigDecimal?

Comment: No, I want to add decimal point to the `totalAmount` if there is no decimal point already .

Comment: Why does `41` become `4.00`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a number with always 2 decimal points using BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515640/how-to-display-a-number-with-always-2-decimal-points-using-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use `setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)` on `BigDecimal` to add decimal places. Remember `BigDecimal` is immutable.

```
if (totalAmount.scale() == 0) {
  totalAmount = totalAmount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `.setScale(2)` just fine, no need to specify RoundingMode.

Comment: Problem is we cannot use variable outside if else . What to do ? My code is focusing on first variable which is `totalAmount = firstAmount.multiply(secondAmount).divide(new BigDecimal("123"), MathContext.DECIMAL128);` and not on if else.