# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when Running Data

Tags: java, arrays

I am still pretty new to learning java and for an assignment I was given a set of data to run with my code.

[image]

After inputting some of the data, this exception appeared

[image]

I can't figure out why an exception is being thrown after I prompt user for money tended by the customer. Help is appreciated. Here is my code below:

```java
public class cashRegister 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //represents the sale amount
        double saleAmt;
        //represents amount of money given by customer
        double cusTend;
        //represents customer's change 
        double cusChange = 0;

        //Collects sale amount from user
        Scanner customerIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the sale amount");
        saleAmt = customerIn.nextDouble();
        //Collects amount tended 
        System.out.println("Please enter amount tended by the customer");
        cusTend = customerIn.nextDouble();
        //Outputs customer's total change
        cusChange = cusTend - saleAmt;
        System.out.printf("Total Change: %.2f", cusChange,"\n");
        //Splits change into Dollars and Cents 
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        String moneyString = decimalFormat.format(cusChange);
        String[] parts = moneyString.split("\\.");
        String part2 = parts[1]; //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException here
        String dollars= parts[0];
        double cents5 = Double.parseDouble(part2);
        //Divides change by amount
        int cents = (int)cents5;
        int quarters = cents / 25;
        int cents1 = cents % 25;
        int dimes = cents1 / 10;
        int cents2 = cents % 10;
        int nickels = cents2 / 5;
        int cents3 = cents % 5;
        int pennies = cents3;

        //Out prints the amount of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickles, and pennies 
        System.out.printf("\n"+ "Dollars :"+ dollars + "\n" );
        System.out.printf("Quarters :" + quarters + "\n");
        System.out.printf("Dimes :"+ dimes +"\n");
        System.out.printf("Nickles :" + nickels +"\n");
        System.out.printf("Pennies :" + pennies + "\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be `moneyString.split("\\.");` returns an array of 1 element.

Comment: By the way, the exception will point to a line number in your code. You could mark the line in the code you copy here.  For example: `int foo = bar / bin;  // **** Division by zero exception here ****`

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Thank you! I updated my post to show which line it was pointing to. I read the thread that you linked and I'm still a little confused. (This was a sample code my tutor told me to follow and it wasn't explained well)

Comment: I would advise against using a floating point type (`double` or `float`) to represent money. It doesn't work well with decimal fractions. Try using an `int` variable that represents cents.  Or use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

When sale amount is 92 and amount tended is 95, the total change is 3.
Hence `moneyString` is 3 and not 3.00
Therefore `moneyString.split("\\.")` will return an array that contains a single element only and that's why you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

You just need to check the number of elements in `parts` and add code that handles different numbers of elements.
Also, as mentioned in the comments, it is better to use class [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for money amounts (rather than `double`).
Refer to this SO question (and answer): [How to display a number with always 2 decimal points using BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515640/how-to-display-a-number-with-always-2-decimal-points-using-bigdecimal)

Note that there is also [Java Money](https://javamoney.github.io/).

It is recommended to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) which means that then name of your class should be `CashRegister` (and not `cashRegister`).
Remember that Java code is case-sensitive.

Here is my rewrite of your code. I check the number of elements in `parts` and handle the case where that number is zero or one or two.

Refer to the *javadoc* for method [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), I think you should change the code that calls that method. I have done so in the below code.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CashRegister {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Collects sale amount from user
        Scanner customerIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the sale amount");
        double tmp = customerIn.nextDouble();

        //represents the sale amount
        BigDecimal saleAmt = new BigDecimal(tmp);

        //Collects amount tended 
        System.out.println("Please enter amount tended by the customer");
        tmp = customerIn.nextDouble();

        //represents amount of money given by customer
        BigDecimal cusTend = new BigDecimal(tmp);

        //Outputs customer's total change
        BigDecimal cusChange = cusTend.subtract(saleAmt);
        cusChange.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        //Splits change into Dollars and Cents
        String moneyString = String.format("%.2f", cusChange.doubleValue());
        System.out.printf("Total Change: %s%n", moneyString);
        String[] parts = moneyString.split("\\.");
        String dollars;
        if (parts.length > 0) {
            dollars = parts[0];
        }
        else {
            dollars = "0";
        }
        String part2;
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            part2 = parts[1];
        }
        else {
            part2 = "0";
        }
        double cents5 = Double.parseDouble(part2);

        //Divides change by amount
        int cents = (int)cents5;
        int quarters = cents / 25;
        int cents1 = cents % 25;
        int dimes = cents1 / 10;
        int cents2 = cents % 10;
        int nickels = cents2 / 5;
        int cents3 = cents % 5;
        int pennies = cents3;

        //Out prints the amount of dollars, quarters, dimes, nickles, and pennies 
        System.out.printf("%nDollars : %s%n", dollars);
        System.out.printf("Quarters: %d%n", quarters);
        System.out.printf("Dimes   : %d%n", dimes);
        System.out.printf("Nickles : %d%n", nickels);
        System.out.printf("Pennies : %d%n", pennies);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample run of the above code:

```
Please enter the sale amount
92.00
Please enter amount tended by the customer
95.00
Total Change: 3.00

Dollars : 3
Quarters: 0
Dimes   : 0
Nickles : 0
Pennies : 0
```