# How to get the 0 at the end of a double?

Tags: java, currency

This is what I have:

```
if (balance * 100 % 10 == 0) {
    balance = balance + 0.00;
}
if (balance > 0) {
    return name + ", $" + balance;
} else if (balance < 0) {
    return name + ", -$" + -balance;
} else { // balance = 0
    return name + ", $0.00";
}
```

I want to return "$4.80" but I keep getting "$4.8". How do I get the 0 at the end of the decimal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, you should never use floating-point numbers (like `double`) for money, since you get rounding errors. Store money in an integer type (for dollars, a `long` of cents) instead and format it for display.

Comment: @hexafraction Yes, but a person could easily have more than $42,949,672.95.

Comment: @hexafraction, AJMansfield Actually, just $21 million! And perhaps the number isn't even an account balance, but the total sales for a year.

Comment: Never mind, argument was a fallacy. Still, if someone's asking here for programming help I wouldn't trust them with $21 million.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's `NumberFormat` or `DecimalFormat`, specifically there is a `getCurrencyInstance` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()