# Software sales errors

Tags: java

I keep getting these error codes:

SoftwareSales.java:20: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable Sales

location: class SoftwareSales

```
  Sales = 99;
  ^
```

SoftwareSales.java:30: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable Sales

location: class SoftwareSales

```
  Total = Quantity * Sales;
                     ^
```

SoftwareSales.java:32: cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable Disount

location: class SoftwareSales

```
  Total = Total - Disount;
                  ^
```

SoftwareSales.java:37: possible loss of precision

found   : float

required: int

```
     Rate = .20f;
            ^
```

SoftwareSales.java:39: possible loss of precision

found   : float

required: int

```
     Rate = .30f;
            ^
```

SoftwareSales.java:41: possible loss of precision

found   : float

required: int

```
     Rate = .40f;
            ^
```

SoftwareSales.java:43: possible loss of precision

found   : float

required: int

```
     Rate = .50f;
            ^
```

7 errors

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoftwareSales
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      Sales = 99;

      int Quantity;
      int Total;
      int Rate;
      double Discount;

      System.out.print ("Enter amount of packages purchased: ");
            Quantity = keyboard.nextInt();

      Total = Quantity * Sales;
      Discount = Total * Rate;
      Total = Total - Disount;

      if(!(Total < 10))
         System.out.println("No discount." + "Your total is: " + Total);
      else if(Total >= 19)
         Rate = .20f;
      else if(Total >= 49)
         Rate = .30f;
      else if(Total >= 99)
         Rate = .40f;
      else
         Rate = .50f;

      System.out.println("Your discount is " + Discount + 
                         ". Your total is: " + Total);
   }
}
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn variable types my friend. Sales is most likely an int so

```
int Sales
```

Rate is a double so

```
double Rate
```

Whole code should be

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoftwareSales
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      int sales = 99;

      int quantity;
      double total;
      double rate = 0; // set rate to what you need.
      double discount;

      System.out.print ("Enter amount of packages purchased: ");
            quantity = keyboard.nextInt();

      total = quantity * sales;
      discount = total * rate;
      total = total - discount;

      if(!(total < 10))
         System.out.println("No discount." + "Your total is: " + total);
      else if(total >= 19)
         rate = .20f;
      else if(total >= 49)
         rate = .30f;
      else if(total >= 99)
         rate = .40f;
      else
         rate = .50f;

      System.out.println("Your discount is " + discount + 
                         ". Your total is: " + total);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the visual aid. I still keep forgetting about the naming conventions and i'll try too keep this in mind.

Comment: Im still getting an error of "possible loss of precision"

for  **`total = total - discount;`**

@Quillion

Comment: Your total is an int, your discount is a double. Therefore the precision lost will be the decimal digits when you are doing the arithmetic. If you want, change the type of total to a double and you are good, no decimal digits will be lost.

Comment: Thank you for your time! It's very much apreciated. @Quillion

Comment: Im very sorry again but another error appeared right after we just fixed this one it says, _"Variable rate might not have been initialized"_ for **`discount = total * rate;`**  @Quillion

Comment: no problem :) glad I can help, you need to have some kind of a value assigned to rate. When you try to calculate discount, it tries to see what rate is, but it has no value assigned. I edit the code for you.

Comment: Ohhhh ok thanks a lot! no error came up but i did see that when i run the code and I entered 1 for the amount of pkgs it would display **"No discount. Your total is 99."** and also **"Your discount is 0.0 your total is 99.0"** I don't want it to show both msgs when its less than 10 and or the decimal point if its a whole number. @Quillion

Comment: Taht's another question and another thing. For showing proper messages I will let you try that yourself. For showing proper numbers look into  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the variable `Sales`. For example:

```
int Sales = 99;
```

The loss-of-precision errors are because you are assigning `float` values to `int` variables. While this is sometimes treated as a warning, it usually indicates an error and requires either declaring the proper variable types or using an explicit cast. Possibly you should declare the variables to be `float`. Alternatively, do all the calculations in integer cent values and avoid potential round-off errors.

Not that you asked about this, but Java naming conventions are for variables to be camel case and start with a lower-case letter: `sales` instead of `Sales` (and `totalSales` instead of `TotalSales`, if you had such a variable name).

Comment: +1. Would also suggest to OP to read up and implement proper java naming syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help and yeah Im still getting the gist of the naming conventions. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make your variables lowercase to avoid confusion with class names. In java class names are always capitalized which may introduce confusion in your code.

You're missing `int sales = 99;` it cannot resolve the symbol because you never declared it.

`Rate` should be a double and you're casting values to float, you can leave off the `.f`

Comment: `Discount` is just a typo. `Rate` is the variable with the float issue and it is because it is declared as an int.

Comment: One of his/her errors was `Discount` typo'd as `Discout`. The other error is that `Rate` is declared as an int not a double or float.

Answer (score 2):

- You haven't defined `Sales`
- You have a typo in `Disount`
- `Rate` should be of type `float`