# How to add a character to different positions of a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string say `1234567890` and I want to append the `,` character to positions in the String so that the string becomes `1,234,567,890`. How do I go about it?

```
If the string has only 4 character like 1234, I could do:
if (str.length() >= 4) {
    str= str.substring(0, str.length()-3)+","+str.substring(str.length() - 3, str.length());
}
```

but how would I do it in case the string is 1234567890?
Thanks.

Comment: I don´t know Java, but isn´t there st. like PHPs `number_format` function?

Comment: Pass the `String` to `StringBuilder`, then insert the `,` at the appropriate points.  Use `StringBuilder#toString` to get the value back.  Of course, you could just use a `NumberFormat`...

Comment: I think, u would like to format the number? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). First turn the String to a number, then format it:

```
double number = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
String formattedString = formatter.format(number);
```

Comment: Yea, this one actually works. It is simple and easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the underlying problem was how to group thousands. If it solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer.