# Correct way to format a notation of a number with decimal scale in Java without dividing

Tags: java, number-formatting, bigdecimal

I have done a reading about number conversions in `Java` because I need to format a number inside my Android application.

I'm currently holding a `long` variable with 4 digits

```
long variable_1 = 2203;
```

And this is what I'm looking to print

```
220.3
```

### What I have done so far

```
variable_1 = 2203;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(variable_1);
bd = bd.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

txtView_variable_1.setText(String.valueOf(bd));
```

Result

```
2203.0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a number in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Comment: try dividing by 10 ?

Comment: Simple workaround, but I'm actually looking forward to know why is it not converting to `220.3`.

Comment: Because 220.3 is not the scientific notation for 2203?

Comment: Is it possible to move the notation instead of dividing by 10?

Comment: How do you determine the number of digits that will go after the decimal point?

Comment: `bd.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);` where 1 is the the `newScale` i.e. number of digits. I know it looks kind of silly, but dividing is *not* the best approach here.

Comment: @Holmes changing the scale will return a new `BigDecimal` with the specified scale but with the same numerical value. It won't change the interpretation of the unscaled number. The underlying scaled number will be rescaled. See my answer for a way to correctly interpret an unscaled number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the scale of a `BigDecimal`, it will return a new `BigDecimal` with the specified scale but with the same numerical value. It won't change the interpretation of the unscaled number. The underlying scaled number will be rescaled.

You should give the scale at the initialization of the BigDecimal in order for it to interpret correctly your unscaled number :

```
long variable_1 = 2203;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(variable_1), 1);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(bd));
```

Which outputs :

```
220.3
```

Comment: Thank you @zakinster. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to round at 0.1
I managed it like this:

```
  private BigDecimal roundBigDecimal(BigDecimal valueToRound) {
    int valeurEntiere = valueToRound.intValue();
    String str = String.valueOf(valeurEntiere);
    int rounding = valeurEntiere == 0 ? 1 : str.length() + 1;
    return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(valueToRound), new MathContext(rounding, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
  }
```

In fact the int rounding depends of the number of digit of the number.