# Parsing string to double/float throwing errors

Tags: java, selenium, type-conversion

I am extracting couple of values like 1234, 2456.00 etc from UI as string. When I try to parse this string to float, 1234 is becoming 1234.0 and when I tried to parse as double its throwing error. How can I solve this?

I am using selenium web driver and java. Below are few things I tried.

```
double Val=Double.parseDouble("SOQ");
double Val=(long)Double.parseDouble("SOQ");``
```

Comment: `"SOQ"` is not a valid numeric string.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with that code.. Please neaten up. Are you just trying to convert a double to a long? or the other way around?

Comment: Ohh I am sorry..SOQ is the string which stores the text value that is extracted from UI. Its a typo while editing.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question.From UI I am extracting the value 2456.00 as string. I parsed it using the code                                                     double X=Double.parseDouble(2456.00); After this the value of X is 2456.0 So what can I do to get the value as 2456.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mixed it up a bit when trying to figure out how to parse the numbers. So here is an overview:

```
// lets say you have two Strings, one with a simple int number and one floating point number
String anIntegerString = "1234";
String aDoubleString = "1234.123";

// you can parse the String with the integer value as  double 
double integerStringAsDoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(anIntegerString);
System.out.println("integer String as double value = " + integerStringAsDoubleValue);

// or you can parse the integer String as an int (of course)
int integerStringAsIntValue = Integer.parseInt(anIntegerString);
System.out.println("integer String as int value = " + integerStringAsIntValue);

 // if you have a String with some sort of floating point number, you can parse it as double
double doubleStringAsDoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(aDoubleString);
System.out.println("double String as double value = " + doubleStringAsDoubleValue);

// but you will not be able to parse an int as double
int doubleStringAsIntegerValue = Integer.parseInt(aDoubleString); // this throws a NumberFormatException because you are trying to force a double into an int - and java won't assume how to handle the digits after the . 
System.out.println("double String as int value = " + doubleStringAsIntegerValue);
```

This code would print out:

```
integer String as double value = 1234.0
integer String as int value = 1234
double String as double value = 1234.123

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1234.123"
```

Java will stop "parsing" the number right when it hits the `.` because an integer can never have a `.` and the same goes for any other non-numeric vales like `"ABC"`, `"123$"`, `"one"` ... A human may be able to read "123$" as a number, but Java won't make any assumptions on how to interpret the "$".

Furthermore: for float or double you can either provide a normal integer number or anything with a `.` somewhere, but no other character besides `.` is allowed (not even `,` or `;` and not even a WHITESPACE)

### EDIT:

If you have a number with "zeros" at the end, it may look nice and understandable for a human, but a computer doesn't need them, since the number is still mathematically correct when omitting the zeros.
e.g. `"123.00"` is the same as `123` or `123.000000` 
It is only a question of formatting the output when printing or displaying the number again (in which case the number will be casted back into a string). You can do it like this:

```
    String numericString = "2456.00 ";  // your double as a string
    double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(numericString);  // parse the number as a real double
      // Do stuff with the double value
    String printDouble = new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(doubleValue); // force the double to have at least 2 digits after the .
    System.out.println(printDouble);  // will print "2456.00"
```

You can find an overview on `DecimalFormat` [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html#number-format-pattern-syntax).

For example the **#** means *"this is a digit, but leading zeros are omitted"* and **0** means *"this is a digit and will not be omitted, even if zero"*

hope this helps

Comment: You don't make a lot of assumptions and keep the explanation concise. Good Answer

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your details. My string value is 2456.00 While I parsed using double it became 2456.0 but I need it as 2456.00 itself

Comment: @Game..Thanks for the info..I tried it out and its working.

Comment: @Aish: aweseome, glad it helped. Would you mind accepting the answer that helped you the most?

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that `"SOQ"` is not a number.

Second, if you want create a number using a `String`, you can use `parseDouble` and give in a value that does not have a decimal point. Like so:

```
Double.parseDouble("1");
```

If you have a value saved as a `long` you do not have to do any conversions to save it as a double. This will compile and print `10.0`:

```
long l = 10l;
double d = l;
System.out.println(d);
```

Finally, please read this [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you cannot parse non-numeric input as a `Double`.

For example:

```
Double.parseDouble("my text");
Double.parseDouble("alphanumeric1234");
Double.parseDouble("SOQ");
```

will cause errors.

but the following is valid:

```
Double.parseDouble("34");
Double.parseDouble("1234.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

The number you want to parse into Double contains "," and space so you need first to get rid of them before you do the parsing

```
String str = "1234, 2456.00".replace(",", "").replace(" ", "");
double Val=Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Comment: Hi..Sorry for the unclear question. There were some typo errors. I was trying to parse the string value 2456.00 to double. But the result I got was 2456.0 What can be done so that I get the value as 2456.00 itself?

Comment: you need something called  DecimalFormat which extends from NumberFormat  please look at  []http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java