# Creating a number with Math.random to the tenths place

Tags: java, arrays

I need to fill an array with random numbers but the the numbers can only go to the tenths place. Is there a way to do that with Math.random? Here is what I have for my `Math.random`:

```
double[] array = new double[size];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    double num = ((Math.random() * 10000.0) + 0.0);
    array[i] = num;
}
return array;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java , I personally can vouch for DecimalFormat

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to make larger random numbers?

Comment: You should be using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`s if you care about exact decimal places.

Comment: If I understand correctly, try looking at `setScale` on the `BigDecimal` class and supply a `RoundingMode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want random number with one decimal place you can use

```
int size = 20;
double[] array = new double[size];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(10_000 * 10) / 10.0;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

prints

[8773.3, 6305.2, 2758.4, 7872.7, 4648.9, 3565.2, 9546.4, 7533.1, 2369.7, 3218.0, 9960.2, 7418.0, 8149.3, 8813.4, 638.5, 8178.9, 2831.2, 4758.7, 8238.2, 6409.1]

Note: while `double` has a representation error, the Double.toString() is written to display the shortest decimal which would have that representation so you don't see any error (nor will you for an number for at least up to 100 trillion for one decimal place)

Note2: this is why you must do a `(x * N) / (double) N` as it avoid cumulated errors. e.g. if you do

```
double y = x * 0.1
```

and

```
double y = x / 10.0;
```

this does not always produce the same result. This is because `0.1` cannot be represented accurately and when you use it in an operation, you compound this error.  If you use `10.0`, it can be represented without error, so the error in the result will be small enough that when you call `Double.toString()` you will get the expected result.