# Java : Parse NumberFormat Object and assign it to Number Object

Tags: java, number-formatting, digits

I had setted maximum fraction digits as 4, 
but why is the output of N.doublevalue() 1234.56789999999 
not 1234.5679?

```
    try{
    NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    NF.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    NF.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
    Number N = NF.parse("1234.56789999999");
    System.out.println(N.doubleValue());
    System.out.println(NF.format(1234.567899999));
    }

    catch(ParseException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: Because you are just printing a `double` which does not have any intrinsic formatting

Comment: What are your specific requirements? For accurate rounding you should use BigDecimal.

Comment: refer this link you will get exact idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java

Comment: Thanks everyone. I saw the code in a book but I don't know how it works so trying to get an answer. I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `N.doubleValue()` actually converts your `Number` to `double`. double is an basic type, it doesn't support any rounding, it is raw floating point value written in memory, it doesn't have the exact value you try to convert it from, so instead it is the best match from the values possible for the `double`. That said, `double` does not have all values that are just possible, because there is a limited memory for it, the double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point., the precision (places after dot) is bigger for small `double` values and lower for bigger ones. Very big `double` numbers doesn't even have any precision after dot at all. The same is with `float`, but float has far less precision than `double`.