# Only need two decimal places in my output

Tags: java, double

How to get the double value that is only two digit after decimal point.
The output I receive gives me BMI = 23.053626543209877 if my height input is 72 and weight 170. I'm not sure how to get rid of the trailing numbers after .05

Here is the code I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class bmi {

```
private static Scanner scanner;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Variables
    double height; 
    double weight; 
    double bmi; 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your height: ");
    height = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if(height<=0)
    {
        System.out.println("That's an invalid height.");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter your weight: ");
    weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if(weight<=0)
    {
        System.out.println("That's an invalid weight.");
        return;
    }

    bmi =  calculateBMI(height, weight);


    System.out.println("BMI = " + bmi);

    System.out.println(bmiDescription(bmi));

    keyboard.close();
}


static double calculateBMI (double height, double weight) {
    return weight * 703 / (height * height);
}


static String bmiDescription (double bmi) {
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        return "You are underweight.";
    } else {
        if (bmi > 25) {
            return "You are overweight.";
        } else {
            return "You are optimal.";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd buy your app if it told me I had a bmi of 23. Have a look at Double.format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a number in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use formatted io with `printf`, like

```
double bmi = 23.053626543209877;
System.out.printf("BMI = %.2f%n", bmi);
```

Outputs (as I believe you wanted, and will even perform rounding)

```
BMI = 23.05
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to maintain precision when dealing with numbers but there are those certain situations where in depth precision is not really a main concern. If you want to set a specific double data type variable to a specific decimal precision then you could pass your Double type value to a method like this:

```
double bmi = round(23.053626543209877, 2);
System.out.println("BMI = " + bmi);

private static double round(double value, int precision) {
    int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
    return (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

Output will be:

```
BMI = 23.05
```

As the method name suggests, the returned result is also rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy method I use:

```
public static double round (double value, int precision) {
    int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
    return (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

Just pass in your value, then pass in precision (the number of decimals to display).

For example: `round(2.3891237, 2)` will return `2.39`

Answer (score 0):

In calculateBMI() do the following.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
numberFormat.format(x);
```

Where **x** will be your calculated double value.