# how to replace string follow by format from user?

Tags: java

```
Input > 
user_input = 123456789
format = "xx-xxx-x-xx-x"

Output >
12-345-6-78-9
```

Or

```
Input > 
user_input = 123456
format = "x-xx-x-x-x"

Output >
1-23-4-5-6
```

I do everything i can and try to another language(python,js) 
but it not work.

[it have problem after else statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piGvP.png)

```
String a = "123456";
String b = "xxx-xx-x";

char[] c_arr = b.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    if(c_arr[i] != '-'){
        c_arr[i] = a.charAt(i);
    } else {
        c_arr[i+1] = a.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(c_arr);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Comment: @Ele it difference that post cause my code have a format from user input

Comment: It's because your `b` string is longer than your `a` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here will solve your problem. What is happening is that your counter variable exceeds the length of the `a` string. To solve that, use a separate counter which iterates through that string that increments as the characters are consumed.

```
String a = "123456";
String b = "xxx-xx-x";

char[] cArray = b.toCharArray();
int aPos = 0; // create separate counter

for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    if (cArray[i] == '-') continue; // if skipping, do not increment aPos, continue
    cArray[i] = a.charAt(aPos);
    aPos++; // add counter when we used the charAt

    System.out.println(cArray);
}
```

This could still break, however, because there could be more positions that are declared in `b` that need to be filled than there are consumable characters in `a`. I would recommend doing a runtime check to throw an exception if there is an input mismatch.

Comment: `if (cArray[i] == '-') continue; rest of code` is similar to `if (cArray[i] == '-'){continue;} else {rest of code}`. In this situation we can rewrite current code as `if(cArray[i]=='x'){cArray[i] = a.charAt(aPos++);}` - System.out.... should also be placed outside of loop.

Comment: Yea, if we weren’t showing the working. The OP has the print statement inside because he wants to know what is going on. I left it in so he could see what is going on.