# How to round number in MonetaryAmount (org.javamoney.moneta)

Tags: java

I am using *org.javamoney.moneta* library to perform some currency conversion. 
After the conversion, I got a number with very long digits after the comma, something like 1234.0000000000000. I would like to have only two digits after the comma. Can anyone give me some idea how to archive this?

Here is my code:

```
    MonetaryAmount sourceAmount= Monetary.getDefaultAmountFactory().setCurrency("USD")
            .setNumber(1234.0).create();
    CurrencyConversion targetConversion = MonetaryConversions.getConversion("EUR");
    MonetaryAmount targetAmount = source.with(targetConversion);
    System.out.println(targetAmout.toString());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

Comment: Are you referring to a decimal point(".") and not comma? If yes use DecimalFormat to format the number.

Comment: Hi, yes I can use DecimalFormat to format the number, but I just want to ask if there is already an integrated method inside of the MonetaryAmount interface which can do the same function.

Comment: Round or format, which one is it?

Comment: Hi, I would like to round the number

Answer (score 0):

In the introduction of "JavaMoney Moneta User Guide" on GitHub there is a reference to the javax.money.format package. When you check out javadox for that package you will find MonetaryAmountFormat interface listed.

This is an example for customizing a format object:

```
MonetaryAmountFormat f = MonetaryFormats.getInstance(loc);

f.setStyle(f.getStyle().toBuilder().setPattern("###.##;(###.##)").build());
```

For further information visit:

http://javadox.com/javax.money/money-api/1.0/javax/money/format/package-summary.html

http://javadox.com/javax.money/money-api/1.0/javax/money/format/MonetaryAmountFormat.html#format-javax.money.MonetaryAmount-