# How to convert NumberFormat

Tags: java, number-formatting

I want to Update a database and want to put the Numbers like this: 1.384,38

Here is my Code to Update from the Textfield but it doesn't work

```
try {
                String query="Update Sina Set Iuuiu = ?  where Formate = ? " ;


                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setDouble(1, Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()));  

                pst.setString(2, "Zuschnittentnahme Gegensauger"); 

                pst.executeUpdate();


                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This is my Code. Now I have to type it like this: 1344.43 but I want to type it like this: 1.344,43

Comment: We'd need a little more context, e.g.: Why do you want to store numbers as strings? What does your update code/query look like? What exacly "doesn't work"? - In general please read [ask] and then update your question accordingly.

Comment: `format(pst.setDouble(...))` what exactly are you trying to do here? Do you realize that `PreparedStatement.setDouble()` doesn't return anything, i.e. `void`?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50543/11905620) might help you concerning number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a number in your default locale use

```
String text = textField_3.getText();
double number = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(text).doubleValue();
pst.setDouble(1, number);
```

or using a given locale:

```
String text = textField_3.getText();
double number = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse(text).doubleValue();
pst.setDouble(1, number);
```

<sup>don't forget a try-catch for the eventual `ParseException` thrown by `parseDouble`</sup>

Comment: How can I put it into my code? I want to set a textfield with a string but the textfield only accept doubles in this format: 133.43

Comment: isn't that a different question?  updated the question to include  possible usage in your code

Comment: just replace your `pst.setDouble(1,...` line by the 3 lines I posted