# Rounding double in Java to appropriate amount

Tags: java, double

I have a double in my Java code that could be very small or very large. I have been trying to find way to round that double to an appropriate amount so that I can display it nicely to the user. For example:

```
0.001 // Rounds to 0.001
0.100001 // Rounds to 0.1
35.00000001 // Rounds to 35
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Look at BigDecimal.

Comment: How are you determining the "appropriate amount"?

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered here: [How do I format a number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java)

DecimalFormat() is what you are looking for.